# Query local variables passed in loop using pandas query function

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to query each column name dynamically given the column names in a list.   I  can use the @sign to pass in dynamically on the other side of the equal sign but I'm really trying to do the columns dynamically..

```
import pandas as pd
import bumpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=list('ab'))
df

columns = ['a','b']

for each_column in columns:
    df.query("@each_column > 1")  ## error
```

Comment: even if we provided you with a string to query with, it's unclear what you're after.  Your code won't produce any output.  What is your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
          a         b
0 -0.272252 -0.467849
1 -0.221294 -2.583866
2 -0.117282  1.044487
3  0.451677 -0.434122
4  0.899038  0.712295
5  1.591961  0.031358
6 -1.398513 -0.600160
7  1.073948  1.348097
8 -1.016790 -0.773364
9 -0.628775  1.116282
```

dynamically generating a query:

```
In [13]: q = ' and '.join('{} > 1'.format(c) for c in df.columns)

In [14]: q
Out[14]: 'a > 1 and b > 1'

In [15]: df.query(q)
Out[15]:
          a         b
7  1.073948  1.348097
```

Comment: not exactly how I was seeing things, but this gives me what I need to solve this.  thanks